# How to get decimal values when the device is in french using NSNumber?

Tags: objective-c, nsnumber, nsnumberformatter

I have an issue with the textfield. This case works fine with the english language. However, if the device language is change to french (canada) , the textfield is not showing the values after the decimal.

For english:

```
  I enter 99.99 and click Done. The text field display 99.99
```

For french:

```
 I enter 99,99 and click Done . The text field display 99,00
```

Here is my code:

```
  _amountField.text = [_amountField currencyFormatFromValue:[NSNumber numberWithDouble:_amountField.text.doubleValue]];
```

Here the `[NSNumber numberWithDouble:_amountField.text.doubleValue]` part is returning 99.99 in case of english and 99,00 in case of french

```
-(NSString *)currencyFormatFromValue:(NSNumber *)value{

    NSNumberFormatter *formatter = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];

    formatter.positiveFormat = @"###.00";
    formatter.roundingMode = NSNumberFormatterRoundFloor;
    [formatter setNumberStyle:NSNumberFormatterCurrencyStyle];
    NSString *groupingSeparator = [[NSLocale currentLocale] objectForKey:NSLocaleGroupingSeparator];
    [formatter setGroupingSeparator:groupingSeparator];
    [formatter setUsesGroupingSeparator:YES];
    [formatter setCurrencySymbol:@""];
    [formatter setMinimumIntegerDigits:1];
    NSString *formattedValue = [formatter stringFromNumber:value];

    return formattedValue;
}
```

I am not sure, why the french text which is converted in double is terminating the decimal values. Any ideas?

Do I need to convert the text back to english before I sent the value to formatter?

Comment: You shouldn't be setting any of the properties of the number formatter other than the style. Let the user's locale define everything else.

Comment: I used groupingseparator to separate hundreds and thousands in the total value. If I just use number style, it doesnt separate the hundreds and thousands

Comment: Just use `setUsesGroupingSeparator:` to turn on grouping. You should not set the actual separator.

Comment: I understand @rmaddy, but we do follow some rules which apply in different scenarios while editing textfield,saving,not saving, resuming...each follows a different format, so I have to use thse!!!

Answer (score 1):

I think your `positiveFormat` specification with the period is conflicting with `NSNumberFormatterCurrencyStyle`. I would try commenting out a bunch of lines and recompiling:

```
NSNumberFormatter *formatter = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];

// formatter.positiveFormat = @"###.00";
// formatter.roundingMode = NSNumberFormatterRoundFloor;
[formatter setNumberStyle:NSNumberFormatterCurrencyStyle];
// NSString *groupingSeparator = [[NSLocale currentLocale] objectForKey:NSLocaleGroupingSeparator];
// [formatter setGroupingSeparator:groupingSeparator];
// [formatter setUsesGroupingSeparator:YES];
// [formatter setCurrencySymbol:@""];
// [formatter setMinimumIntegerDigits:1];
NSString *formattedValue = [formatter stringFromNumber:value];

return formattedValue;
```

In my experience, the formatting out of the box will include grouping separator, currency symbols, rounding mode, etc. Specifying it again can potentially confuse the formatter.

If you **really** need to explicitly specify the positive format, you can try building the positive format string using the `NSLocaleDecimalSeparator` constant so that it will be a period or comma as required:

```
NSString *decimalSeparator = [[NSLocale currentLocale] objectForKey:NSLocaleDecimalSeparator];
formatter.positiveFormat = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"###%@00", decimalSeparator];
```

But I don't recommend it!

Comment: I need that because I need to add .00 at the end if I dont enter any decimal values

Comment: Revised to include alternative, but I'm really surprised the default isn't handling `.00` and `,00` on its own.

Comment: Do not do this. By default, the number formatter will have the correct format based on the user's locale.

Comment: @maddy - I agree, but WCYD?

Answer (score 0):

I found a way to make it work. I need to remove the , character in case of french that occur in the text field and send to formatter .

```
 _amountField.text = [_amountField currencyFormatFromValue:[NSNumber numberWithDouble:[_amountField.text strippedAmount]doubleValue]];
```

and

```
 //macro

#define IsFrenchLanguage() ([[[NSLocale preferredLanguages] objectAtIndex:0] rangeOfString:@"fr"].location != NSNotFound)

-(NSString *) strippedAmountString
{
    NSString * thousandsSeparator = IsFrenchLanguage() ? @" " : @",";
    return [self.amountField.text stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:thousandsSeparator withString:@""];
}
```